# Get rid of empty lists in a result of calling a sequence of nested functions

Tags: functional-programming, erlang, nested, nested-lists

Let's say we have a function:

```
generate([],Result) ->
    Result;
generate([H|T],Result) ->
    case H > 0 of
        true -> generate(T,[H*2|Result]);
        false -> generate(T,Result)
    end.
```

So, basically the function does something with each `H` and adds this something to `Result`.

Now, if I call `generate()` from another function:

```
do_generate([],Result) ->
    Result;
do_generate([List|Other_lists],Result) ->
    do_generate(Other_lists,[generate(List,[])|Result]).
```

The problem is that I do not want the `do_generate()` function to add an empty list `[]` to its result. What if I call `do_generate([[0,0],[1,2]],[])`? I can end up with something like this: `[[2,4],[]]`.

If I embed `do_generate()` into other functions I might end up with even more empty lists inside the result list, which is very inconvenient for later use.

How can I avoid adding `[]` to `Result` in other way than checking with `case generate(List,[]) == [] of` each time?

Is there any 'best practice' for calling a sequence of deeply nested functions and getting rid of empty lists `[]` in the final result with ease?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get rid of all empty lists from the result, like

```
 do_generate([],Result) -> [M|| M <-  Result, length(M) >0];
```

Comment: Just a minor tip: Even though length is fast, this filter can in general become slow for very big lists. Better write it like this:

    do_generate([],Result) -> [M || [_|_] = M <-  Result];

Comment: `[M || M <-  Result, (begin (if M == [] ->  false;true -> true end) end)];` This avoids that `length` function

Answer (score 0):

This hides the filtering well enough:

```
do_generate(Input) ->
    [Res || [_|_] = Res <- [generate(List,[]) || List <- Input]].
```

Answer (score 0):

lists:flatmap might do what you want

Answer (score -1):

You can simply filter the value:

```
do_generate([List|Other_lists],Result) ->
    GenRes = generate(List,[]),
    case GenRes of 
        [] -> do_generate(Other_lists, Result);
        _  -> do_generate(Other_lists,[GenRes|Result])
    end.
```

Comment: Isac, that is the way I am trying to avoid - imagine, I have many functions similar to generate(). Then in each do_fun() I would have to introduce this bulky 'case GenRes of' construction in every function.

Comment: I think this is better than doing the filtering after the fact using lists comprehension or lists:filter.